# Are ghosts real?

Tags: jinn, sihr

I have read from a different post that ghosts do not exist according to Islam. My parents used to work at a kindergarten. They used to clean there after it closed. Sometimes music would randomly start playing without anyone being in that room. My fathers bucket of water would also fall multiple times. My father has talked to a ghost there. He said that he was killed over 200 years ago and has been there since. My mother has heard him talk to the ghost but she has not seen it herself. My father used to pray there aswell. He told me that sometimes when he finished the salah, the ghost would be sitting next to him. There has been other places my father has seen ghosts. At another place, there was another ghost. My father told it that he simply wanted to do his job. The ghost disappeared and my father has not seen it again. I am very unsure if ghosts are real. Is it possible that these encounters was part of my fathers imagination? Or are ghosts real?
Allah SWT knows best. May Allah protect us all.

Answer (score 0):

Shaytan are jinn which we would consider ghosts, they can harm humans and get violent however they can’t kill us